# Private IP disclosure

Tags: php, security, http, response, ip-address

I'm using a security scanning tool to check for vulnerabilities of my web application.

One of the results is a low warning about a private IP which has been found in the HTTP response body. The suggested solution is to remove it but I have no idea how.

I've been through the code and I don't appear to have actually written the IP address anywhere so I'm a bit confused by that.

How do I remove this from the HTTP response?

I am using an apache server on a Linux machine.

Comment: What application and/or framework are you running?

Comment: This is most likely in headers of apache server.

Comment: I am using LimeSurvey v1.90

Comment: edvinas.me - so do I just need to edit the httpd.conf do you think?

Comment: @Gowri stop marking up words as code.

Answer (score 1):

In a certain configuration, the Apache web server may disclose internal IP addresses used by the web server to remote users.

It is reported that if the ServerName directive is not set (or is set to the internal IP) and the UseCanonicalName option is On (which is the default configuration), Apache will return internal IP address information to remote users.

The solution reported is to either set CanonicalName to Off or set the ServerName variable to the external hostname.

http://securitytracker.com/id/1002188